# If-then-else logic to decide which select statement to run

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on some scripting, and I'm trying to figure out how to add the proper logic so that depending on what a variable that is passed in is (I'll use x as an example), that one of two select statements will run. Here's a simple example of what I'm looking for:

two select statements options
X equals either "1" or "2"

**if X equals 1 then run "select * from table where y=3 and z=4;"**

**if X equals 2 then run "select * from table where y=3 and z=5 and q=6 and r=12;"**

The fact that the where clauses are different for the two statements is causing me issues since it makes it harder to do a CASE statement how I normally would.

The first thing that came to my mind was to do something that would do something like a case statement in the from clause so that I could do something like:

```
    select * from 
    (
    case when x=1 then (select 1 from dual)
    case when x=2 then (select 2 from dual)
    )
```

But I know this doesn't work and I'm not sure of anyway to add this kind of logic to a from clause.

To summarize, I'm trying to run one of two possible queries depending on the value of a variable that is passed into the SQL, but the two queries have different where clauses that make it harder to have a case statement in the where clause. I'd appreciate any input or suggestions on how to tackle this issue.

Thanks in advanced guys!

Comment: Do you need to select from same table with different WHERE condition?

Comment: Yes, the two statements select from the same table, with different where conditions (the where conditions are also different lengths)

Answer (score 2):

Use simple `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE (:X = 1 AND y=3 AND z=4)
   OR (:X = 2 AND y=3 and z=5 and q=6 and r=12);
```

Comment: I should have been more clear, the variable X is not in "your_table" it is a variable passed in from a unix script into the sql script. So, depending on what value of X is passed in (out of 2 possibilities) I want to run one of two different queries.

Comment: @corn503 but X is variable, see `:X`, it is exclusive so it end with one path 1 or 2

Comment: Ahh, I misread your answer slightly. Thanks, this works well for what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is not necessarily the most efficient way to do it especially in your case, because you have a relatively simple task in mind. However, it is worth mentioning that for this case and even more complicated cases you can always write a procedure:

```
drop procedure if exists optionalClause;
CREATE PROCEDURE optionalClause()
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `optionalClause`()
begin
    DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;
    /* determining the value of x, for example using select into statement*/

    if @x=1 then
        /* select statement 1 */
    end if;

    if @x=2 then
        /* select statement 2 */
    end if;

END;
$$ DELIMITER ;
CALL optionalClause();
```

and of course you can have else statement instead of two separate if-statements and make it as complicated as you want. Good Luck!

Comment: What DB engine is that for? OP is asking for Oracle, and that does not look like PL/SQL. @ variables are often SQL Server, but that's not SQL Server either.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance. You're right! It is MySQL. He didn't mention anything in the question btw.

Comment: The question is tagged [oracle], which is for the Oracle Database.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something along these lines, replace the variable with the correct integer from your select statement.

```
declare @x int = 2

if @x = 1 goto No1
if @x = 2 goto No2

No1:

print ('This is x = 1')
select * from table where y=3 and z=4;

goto TheEnd

No2:

print ('This is x = 2')
select * from table where y=3 and z=5 and q=6 and r=12;

goto TheEnd

TheEnd:

Print('you made it')
```

Comment: Yes, I find it simple to follow and you can slice up your code into neat bundles.

Comment: Easy to read at the beginning and you end up with unmaintainable code :) [Spaghetti_code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)

Answer (score 0):

CASE is going to give you IF-THEN logic within a SELECT statement. For example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN x=1 THEN field1 ELSE field2 END AS [Conditional Field]
FROM tablename;
```

Alternatively, you can use [IF-THEN-ELSE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php) to run one statement or another. For example:

Comment: I guess `THEN` is missed.

Comment: fixed the typo where i Had else else. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm